# How to select a value according to their spatial position?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I would like to display the name of the countries in the center of each of those present on the output map. Is this possible directly from the `word` variable?

```
library(sp)

names(world)

saudi = world[world$name_long == "Saudi Arabia", ]
plot(st_geometry(saudi), expandBB = c(0, 0.2, 0.1, 1), col = "gray", lwd = 2)
plot(world[0], add = TRUE)
```

[image]

I would just like this case:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very simple solution using `tmap`. Please find the reprex just below and, of course, feel free to adjust the parameters to get the exact rendering you wish.

**Reprex**

```r
library(sf)
library(tmap)

data(World)
Saudi <-  World[World$name == "Saudi Arabia", ]

tm_shape(Saudi, bbox = st_as_sfc(st_bbox(c(st_bbox(Saudi)[1:2]*0.8,st_bbox(Saudi)[3:4]*1.2))))+
  tm_fill("grey")+
  tm_borders(lty = "solid", lwd = 4, col = "black")+
  tm_text("name", size = 1.3)+
  tm_shape(World)+
  tm_borders(col = "black")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

And if you really do not want the frame (I also adjusted the zoom level differently from the first example to show you how it works):

```r
tm_shape(Saudi, bbox = st_as_sfc(st_bbox(c(st_bbox(Saudi)[1:2]*0.6,st_bbox(Saudi)[3:4]*1.3)))) +
  tm_fill("grey") +
  tm_borders(lty = "solid", lwd = 3, col = "black") +
  tm_text("name", size = 1.3) +
  tm_shape(World) +
  tm_borders(col = "black") +
  tm_layout(frame = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

And finally a last rendering with the names (here the iso code) of the surrounding countries:

```r
World2 <- World[!(World$iso_a3 == "SAU"), ]
tm_shape(Saudi, bbox = st_as_sfc(st_bbox(c(st_bbox(Saudi)[1:2]*0.6,st_bbox(Saudi)[3:4]*1.3)))) +
  tm_fill("grey") +
  tm_borders(lty = "solid", lwd = 3, col = "black") +
  tm_text("name", size = 1.3) +
  tm_shape(World2) +
  tm_borders(col = "black") +
  tm_text("iso_a3", size = 0.7, size.lowerbound = TRUE, print.tiny = TRUE, remove.overlap = TRUE) +
  tm_layout(frame = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <-
  map_data("world") %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  filter(region %in% c("United Arab Emirates", "Saudi Arabia"))
data
#> # A tibble: 619 x 6
#>     long   lat group order region               subregion   
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <chr>                <chr>       
#>  1  53.9  24.2    11   959 United Arab Emirates Abu al Abyad
#>  2  53.9  24.1    11   960 United Arab Emirates Abu al Abyad
#>  3  53.8  24.2    11   961 United Arab Emirates Abu al Abyad
#>  4  53.8  24.1    11   962 United Arab Emirates Abu al Abyad
#>  5  53.7  24.1    11   963 United Arab Emirates Abu al Abyad
#>  6  53.6  24.2    11   964 United Arab Emirates Abu al Abyad
#>  7  53.7  24.2    11   965 United Arab Emirates Abu al Abyad
#>  8  53.8  24.3    11   966 United Arab Emirates Abu al Abyad
#>  9  53.9  24.2    11   967 United Arab Emirates Abu al Abyad
#> 10  53.9  24.2    11   968 United Arab Emirates Abu al Abyad
#> # … with 609 more rows

region_names <-
  data %>%
  group_by(region) %>%
  summarise(long = mean(long), lat = mean(lat))
region_names
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   region                long   lat
#>   <chr>                <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Saudi Arabia          44.9  23.2
#> 2 United Arab Emirates  54.4  24.3

data %>%
  ggplot(aes(long, lat)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(color = region), fill = "white") +
  geom_text(
    data = region_names,
    mapping = aes(label = region)
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks but it's maybe probably simpler that your solution. I edited the question with an example.

Comment: I did the *centering* by calculating the mean coordinates per region. I do not know how your variable called `world` looks like, thus I used `ggplot2::map_data("world")` as an example data. If you just want to put the labels anywhere within the country polygon so that the text does not overlap and is readable, you can just go with pre-rendered tiled maps.

Comment: I used exactly the example [here](https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/spatial-class.html#base-args) for the world variable. I'm really a beginner with r.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative version could be to use `geom_sf_text`

Note: I am using `tmap` package to be able to get `World` dataset

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)

data(World)

saudi <- World[World$name == "Saudi Arabia", ]
saudiBbox <- st_bbox(saudi)

ggplot(saudi) + 
  geom_sf(data = World, fill = 'white') + 
  geom_sf() +
  coord_sf(
    xlim = c(saudiBbox['xmin'], saudiBbox['xmax']), 
    ylim = c(saudiBbox['ymin'], saudiBbox['ymax'])
  ) + 
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = name), size = 3, family = "sans") +
  theme_void()
```

which gives:

[image]